Return only the unique values from collection, removing all occurrences of duplicates
Assuming I have some collection, how could I return only those values that appear exactly once? I don't want to reduce duplicate values down to a single entry, I want to eliminate them completely - these are non-valid for my use case.
As an example, a list containing 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 1 should only return 2, 4, 5. I could loop over the list, count the elements and then remove all that appear more than once, but I'm wondering if there's a .stream() solution I'm missing.

For small lists: list.stream().filter(i -> Collections.frequency(list, i) == 1).toList();

To return only elements that appear exactly once, you can use Stream to achieve that:
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 1);

//Find Number of occurence of each element in the List 

Map<Integer, Long> counts = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));

// Filter elements that appear only once

List<Integer> result = list.stream()
    .filter(element -> counts.get(element) == 1)
    .toList();


You could directly stream the entry set of the map and filter by the value. Like this you can avoid the search for each element.

maybe list.stream().collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting())).entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue()==1).map(Map.Entry::getKey).toList()

For something like this I prefer an imperative approach using sets.

Allocate a set to hold seen values
first, add the value to the result set.
but if it was already seen, remove it.

Because sets are hashed and can't hold duplicates the adding and removal is more efficient compared to lists.
List<Integer> list = 
         new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 1));
System.out.println("Original list = " + list);

Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
for(int v : list) {
     result.add(v);  // try and add the value
     if (!seen.add(v)) { // if already seen, remove it.
         result.remove(v);
     }
}

System.out.println("Result = " + result);

prints
Original list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 1]
Result = [2, 4, 5]

The result set can then be put into a list if required.
Stream version
Here's a stream equivalent of the above.

it uses a record to hold the seen and result sets.
it wraps the resultant set in a list.

 record Info(Set<Integer> seen, Set<Integer> result){}

 List<Integer> resultList =
      new ArrayList<>(list.stream().reduce(
         new Info(new HashSet<>(), new HashSet<>()), 
         (info, val) -> {
             info.result.add(val);
             if (!info.seen.add(val)) {
                 info.result.remove(val);
             }
             return info;
         },
         (a, b) -> a).result);
 System.out.println(resultList);
 

If I were doing this I would stick with the imperative solution as it is simpler and the stream solution is not really more declarative but it is more complex.

I like attempting one line stream answers. I'd never write it like this in code shared with others. The use of method references captures value of intermediate sets:
List<Integer> unique = list.stream()
    .filter(Predicate.not(list.stream().filter(Predicate.not(new HashSet<>()::add)).collect(Collectors.toSet())::contains))
    .toList();

A HashSet of seen items is used to create Set of those which are duplicates, which in turn is used to filter down the unique items in  the original list.
It is clearer what is going on above if you refactor it by pulling out intermediate stages as local variables:
// Define a set to record all seen integers:
Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();

// Create a set containing all duplicated integers
// this relies on seen.add(x) returning false for each duplicate  item:
Set<Integer> dups = list.stream()
                        .filter(Predicate.not(seen::add))
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

// Finally scan the list and eliminate every entry which is a duplicate:
List<Integer> unique = list.stream()
    .filter(Predicate.not(dups::contains))
    .toList();

